# Code skips 6 lines of code on its own, what could be wrong here?

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my code, it skips 6 lines of code, and I don't know what the problem could be. I'm just practicing C++, making a bank app, and in the registration menu it skips 6 lines of code for some reason. I would appreciate any help or suggestion! The code can look a little dirty. I don't understand why the code skips the input for the cityAddress, stateAddress, zipAddress after I type the houseAddress input.

```
// Registration menu code
void registerMenu() {
    bool registerSuccess = false;
    bool usernameSuccess = false;
    string saveInfo;

    system("CLS"); // Clear Console

    cout << "Please create your account.\n";
    
    cout << "First Name: ";
    cin >> firstName;
    cout << "Last Name: ";
    cin >> lastName;
    cout << "Phone Number: ";
    cin >> phoneNumber;
    cout << "Address: ";
    cin >> houseAddress;
    cout << "City: ";
    cin >> cityAddress;
    cout << "State: ";
    cin >> stateAddress;
    cout << "Zip code: ";
    cin >> zipAddress;
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "Save information?\nY/N\n";
    cin >> saveInfo;

    if (saveInfo == "Y") {
        cout << "-----------INFORMATION SAVED!-----------\n";
    }
    else if (saveInfo == "N") {
        registerMenu();
    }
    else {
        registerMenu();
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
    do {
        cout << "Username: ";
        cin >> username;

        ifstream usernameCheck("user_" + username + ".txt");
        if (usernameCheck.is_open()) {
            cout << "This username already exists. Create a different username.\n\n";
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        else {
            cout << "\n\t! USERNAME AVAILABLE !\n";
            usernameSuccess = true;
        }
    } while (!usernameSuccess);

    do {
        cout << "Password: ";
        cin >> password;

        if (password.length() >= 8) {
            cout << "Initial deposit to your account: $";
            cin >> balance;
            system("CLS"); // Clear Console

            cout << "Registration complete!\n";

            // [START] Create Account file
            ofstream registration;
            registration.open("user_" + username + ".txt");
            registration << username << endl << password << endl << balance;
            registration.close();
            // [FINISH] Create Username file

            registerSuccess = true;
            password = password;

            Sleep(1000);
            system("CLS"); // Clear Console
            cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "    Account Information\n";
            cout << "Username: " << username << endl;
            cout << "Password: " << password << endl;
            cout << "Balance: $" << balance << endl;
            cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "Forwarding you in 5 seconds..." << endl;
            Sleep(5000);
            mainMenu();

        }
        else {
            cout << "\n\nPassword must contain at least 8 characters. (You entered " << password.length() << " characters)\nPlease try again.\n";
        }
    } while (!registerSuccess);

}
```

Comment: usually it means you have bad input.

Comment: I'll take a wild guess that is has to do with the way `cout` is buffered.  `cout`'s buffer only gets flushed when you output a newline character (`\n`) or when you explicitly output a `std::flush`.  I suggest you change the output-lines in yoru program to either e.g. `cout << "State:\n"` or  `cout << "State: " << std::flush;` and see if that helps.

Comment: ”cin >>” does - if I remember correctly from my C++ days - not do well with spaces in the input, so I’m guessing your input for house address contains spaces. cin.getline() may work better.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner -- `std::cout` and `std::cin` are (by default) synchronized, and calling a stream extractor will flush the output buffer. So each of those `cin >> xxx` flushes the previous output.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson -- `std::cin >> xxx` does just fine with spaces in the input. What confuses beginners is that a space is a delimiter, so if you type `abcd efg` in response to that prompt the extractor will only read up to the space, and leave the rest of the input for the next extractor.

Answer (score 2):

Home addresses usually have spaces in them. Cin reads up to the first delimiter which is a space. Instead, try
std::getline(cin, houseAddress)